# Why aren't Facebook share images showing up properly in notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I very carefully followed [Facebook's instructions for creating a share dialog with an image](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices), and it works perfectly:

[image]

But when the recipient is actually notified, the image is resized and truncated awkwardly:

[image]

This makes no sense to me. What's the point of making the send dialog show an image that's nothing like what will actually be sent? And is there any way to fix this so that the received notification thumbnail can be specified, so that the send dialog looks good AND the thumbnail looks good?

Comment: How the it is displayed when it is received depends on a huge amount of things. The preview will never be 100% what the user receives. For example if someone receives the message on a feature phone I will assume that we don't show the thumbnail at all.

Comment: But surely when it's received on the same PC screen that sent it, as in my test, it should look the same. They actually state that the aspect ratio is a very specific `1.91:1`, but then crop it to square in the notification window.

Comment: Correct. It does that for you.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't *want* it to do that for me.

Comment: I'm saying you can't change it. You have no control of how it is displayed in Messenger.

Comment: Sigh. So is it just a design problem at Facebook that they clearly specify one aspect ratio for the image and then use a different one in Messenger?